# Calculating the propability of a sum of poisson distributed random variables

Tags: java, math, random

In Java, I have a set of users, each of which has a poisson-distributed demand with a known mean:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.PoissonDistribution;

public class User {
  private int mean;
  private PoissonDistribution dist;
  public void setMean(int mean) {
      this.mean = mean;
      this.poissonDistribution = new PoissonDistribution(mean);
  }
}

...
User u1 = new User(); u1.setMean(20);
User u2 = new User(); u2.setMean(30);
User u3 = new User(); u3.setMean(40);
```

Now I'd like to calculate the probability that all `User`s have a cumulated demand below a certain value:

```
double probabilityBelowX = calculateCumulatedProbability(50, u1, u2, u3); // <- what must this method look like?
```

I am stuck at the question, how to solve this problem in Java. Am I missing something in the math package? I know that the demands of the customers are independent, so according to my knowledge about the poisson distribution I can simply add up the values. But I only have `cumulativeProbability(int x)` for every single one of the user demands, but not for several at once?

Please point me into the right direction, maybe I am using a completely wrong approach. Also, if this problem is better suited on another site of stackexchange, I'd move it.

Comment: This sounds more like a stats problem than a programming problem; probably better off at http://stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will try there as well. I just posted here because IMHO the problem is more about the actual programming than the underlying probability complexity. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you point out, [the sum of independent Poisson distributions is again a Poisson distribution](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_independent_Poisson_random_variables_is_Poisson), with parameter equal to the sum of the parameters of the original distributions.

So in `calculateCumulatedProbability` you need to create a new `PoissonDistribution` object with mean equal to the sum of the means of `u1`, `u2` and `u3` (so `PoissonDistribution(20+30+40)` in this case).  Then the `cumulativeProbability` method on that object will give you the probability you need.

You'll need a `getMean` method on `User` so that you can retrieve the means for the individual users.  Also, are there always 3 users?  If not, wouldn't you be better off having `calculateCumulatedProbability` take just two parameters: a list of users, and the value for the probability computation?

Comment: Thank you! I just wasn't sure if I could simply use the mean of every single distribution, that just seemed to be too simple! But yes, it works and so far, it looks right!